# what's different between reactDom and react-dom in webpack external setting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

when i use webpack setting like this,ReactDOM will exclude from bundle.js exactly

```
externals: {
        "react": "React",
        "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
    },
```

but at first,i wrote like this

```
externals: {
        "react": "React",
        "reactDom": "ReactDOM"
    },
```

and the reactDom include in bundle.js,and added over 20k lines code

only different is i removed the "-"

i thought i can use any name in external key,eg.{"jq":"jquery"}

but the result tell me not

so what the matter exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties of the 'externals' object consist of a key and a value. The name of the key must be the same as the name that is being used to define the module being referenced from a js-file.

E.g. when you reference React DOM in a module like below:

```
var ReactDOM = require("react-dom");
```

The name of the property in the 'externals' configuration object must be 'react-dom'. Only then it will be excluded from the created package.

Comment: yes,i know that.but i didn't find any code like require("react-dom")

Comment: React itself references React-DOM. This might be the reason that you have a inclusion of React-DOM's code in your custom bundle.